# Convert java bean to json string using Struts

Tags: java, json, struts, javabeans

I want to use struts to render content in a JSP page.

I have the Java Bean class implementing `Serializable`:

```
public class MyPOJO implements Serializable {
    String name;
    int value;
    // A lot of other members, but all String or int
    // Getters and setters
}
```

And my form class with a list of MyPOJO:

```
public class MyForm extends ActionForm {
    private List<MyPOJO> results = new ArrayList<MyPOJO>();
    // Getter and setter
}
```

And a class inheriting DispatchAction to pass a MyForm object onto the page.

On the jsp page I use:

```
<logic:notEmpty name="myForm" property="results">
var jsonData = ${myForm.results};
</logic:notEmpty>
```

The final result in the generated jsp file is a list of MyPOJO objects:

> var jsonData = [com.package.MyPOJO@174aee5, ...]

I'd like to know, without overriding `toString()` method inside MyPOJO class is there any other way to directly convert it to json String? I've also created a rest service returning a list of MyPOJO, without the `toString()` method, it can already show the JSON string, I'd like to know why it doesn't work for the JSP form bean?

Comment: That's because the REST framework (Jax-RS, I presume) transforms the objects you return into JSON. It doesn't happen magically. If you want JSON, then use a JSON marshaller (Jackson, Gson, etc. etc.) to transform your objects into a JSON String. Why are you using a deprecated taglib (logic) of an abandoned framework (Struts)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Because it is a very old project I'm working on...

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't override `ArrayList` `toString()` method. Your property is a collection that has to be serialied to JSON. You could either extend `ArrayList` and override that method or use natively `JSONArray` or `JSONObject` `toString()` that is already overridden and returns a JSON string.